# How can I detect sold-out tickets using the EventBrite API?

Tags: eventbrite

Event 6274606517 has multiple types of tickets, some of which have already ended. Two of the future tickets are sold out, two aren't. How can I get that information via the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this in [event_get](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/) by inspecting the `tickets` node.

Each ticket will include `quantity_available` and `quantity_sold`, in addition to other fields which I've left out:

```
"ticket": {
  "currency": "USD", 
  "quantity_available": 6, 
  "quantity_sold": 1, 
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that you *must* pass in your `user_key` to identify yourself as the owner of this event, since ticket sales are considered private.

If sold >= available, the ticket will be sold out.

Comment: Here is one "ticket" for the event in question, without the quantity fields you've mentioned:
        "ticket": {
          "description": "",
          "end_date": "2013-05-06 18:00:00",
          "min": 1,
          "max": null,
          "price": "128.49",
          "visible": "false",
          "currency": "USD",
          "type": 0,
          "id": 18192133,
          "name": "Monday, May 6, 7-10pm"
        }
      },

Comment: clarification: none of the ticket objects have those fields, I just only had room to quote one of them

Comment: How are authenticating?  My guess you you are passing in an app_key, without the user_key.  Make sure to pass in a user_key and the quantity fields will be returned.

Comment: I am not the owner of the event. However, the ticket sales are visible on the web site to non-owners, which is why I expect to get that info from the API.

Comment: Unfortunately there is some disconnect with the way the website works and the way the API behaves.  In this scenario, I think what you are expecting is completely valid.  Arguably "quantity_sold" is still a private field, but the available should be returned.  Do you have the possibility of becoming a sub-user for the event organizer's account?  That way, you would have access to "private" data like this.